# extracting a number from a set of numbers

Tags: r, regex

I have the following set of numbers. I need to write a regex to exclude the first number (24.00) in the set. How can I do that in general, or more specifically in R? I've tried [^24.00] with no luck. Any help please.

```
> 24.00 32824.637 15228.005 12171.46 4468.862 12898.464 5344.394 2342.57 
5029.098 725193.312 703328.437 667.072 2707.375  
15991.489 11449.667 5172.415 2345.175 3788.761 3543.821 1891.775 4917.051 
714035.5 691709.438 682.707 1873.534         
9659.517 11066.622 3327.543 1761.487 1868.323 3421.35 1175.193 3507.34 
528521.687 516397.187 250.152 1417.528          
5654.478 10415.184 1519.152 1451.403 898.984 3038.305 682.707 2918.44 
184953.547 173514.313 343.959 865.109            
2465.04 10386.521 664.466 1443.586 307.479 3517.763 523.756 2749.067 
42770.785 43617.656 349.171 1024.06               
854.686 10852.95 205.854 1732.824 80.778 3317.12 453.401 2876.748 10751.326 
10954.574 221.489 1011.031                 
244.941 10058.196 75.567 1537.393 52.115 3176.41 479.458 2822.028 3134.718 
3343.178 333.536 971.945                    
72.961 10089.465 41.692 1506.124 46.904 3017.459 495.093 2707.375 304.873 
760.879 237.123 979.762
```

[image]

Comment: The format is not clear.  Is it a single string?  Could you edit the post with the `dput` of the example

Comment: Do you want to exclude the first number from every row or just the first row?

Comment: I pretty much want to write a regex to exclude the number 24.00 in the first line.

Comment: `[^24.00]` means "One character, which is not a `2`, `4`, `.` or `0`", by the way. That's clearly not what you want, which is why it's not working as you expect.

Comment: This would be much easier if you convert the string into a numeric vector, or a list of numeric vectors. Is there any particular reason for why you are treating the numbers as character?

Comment: how would I convert the following line into a numeric object : " 24.00 32824.637 15228.005 12171.46 4468.862 12898.464 5344.394 2342.57 5029.098 725193.312 703328.437 667.072 2707.375  "

Comment: Assuming it is stored as `txt`, this should do: `as.numeric(strsplit(txt, " ")[[1]])`

Comment: do you know of an alternative to strsplit() because I would like to have a vector output, not a list

Comment: That's why I included the `[[1]]`. That makes it a vector.

Comment: yeah but there's no other way to do it because I would like to have the various string as different vectors?

Comment: If you want to collapse that list into a single vector you could just use `unlist()` or `do.call(c, )`. `list2env()` can be used to separate the vectors, but having them in a list object can be very handy. Referencing and operating on them is simple using `lapply()`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to match the pattern of one or more digits with dots from the start (`^`) of the string and then replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("^[0-9.]+\\s*", "", trimws(txt))
#[1] "32824.637 15228.005 12171.46 4468.862 12898.464 5344.394 2342.57 5029.098 725193.312 703328.437 667.072 2707.375"
```

If the lines are separate strings, the above code should work fine for 'n' number of lines

```
sub("^[0-9.]+\\s*", "", trimws(txt1))
#[1] "32824.637 15228.005 12171.46 4468.862 12898.464 5344.394 2342.57 5029.098 725193.312 703328.437 667.072 2707.375"
#[2] "32824.637 15228.005 12171.46 4468.862 12898.464 5344.394 2342.57 5029.098 725193.312 703328.437 667.072 2707.375"
```

#### data

```
txt <- c(" 24.00 32824.637 15228.005 12171.46 4468.862 12898.464 5344.394 2342.57 5029.098 725193.312 703328.437 667.072 2707.375")
txt1 <- c(txt, txt)
```

Comment: @DiegoSalazar  It is working for me with the example updated\

Comment: yeah with your code is fine, but with my object is not working

Comment: @DiegoSalazar Now, I understand why.  You have a space at the begginning.  Just do `trimws(txt)` and then use `sub`  Updated the code\

Comment: I tried this code and it modified the subsequent lines as well and obviously that's not what was supposed to happen. My object has 8 lines.

Comment: @DiegoSalazar  It should work if there are 1 line or n lines as long as these are separate strings.  Let me update the answer and show

Comment: I tried this code as per your suggestion texttosearch1_c <- sub("^[0-9.]+\\s*.", "", trimws(texttosearch1_b))

Comment: @DiegoSalazar  If you check the updated code, it is working for me for multiple lines.  It is always better to post with `dput`,

Comment: so when I dput the results I get the following:

Comment: "0386.521 664.466 1443.586 307.479 3517.763 523.756 2749.067 42770.785 43617.656 349.171 1024.06"

Comment: @DiegoSalazar  Isn't it the expected output?

Comment: @DiegoSalazar  Can you also try `sub("^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*\\s*", "", trimws(txt1))`

Comment: your last code takes out the first number from each line

Comment: @DiegoSalazar  As I mentioned with the text example, it is working for me

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it using `sub`:

```
x <- c("24.00 32824.637 15228.005 12171.46 4468.862 12898.464 5344.394 2342.57 5029.098 725193.312 703328.437 667.072 2707.375")
y <- sub("\\S+ ", "", x) # substitute everything up to the first space with the empty string
y
# [1] "32824.637 15228.005 12171.46 4468.862 12898.464 5344.394 2342.57 5029.098 725193.312 703328.437 667.072 2707.375"
```

Comment: the 'y' output should be like akrun's answer. in here 24.32824.637 is not the right number.

Comment: Yup, missed that. Fixed now.

Comment: Your code works when you have a vector of one string, but do you know how to do it when you have multiple strings in the same vector (as displayed in the picture in my question)?